# How to plot user availability?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following data set and am looking to plot a square wave in Excel using the on/off as the trigger.

```
Agent   On/Off        LogDate
Will     On    7/19/2022  6:35:38 AM
Charles  On    7/19/2022  6:49:51 AM
Mason    On    7/19/2022  6:50:46 AM
Charles  Off   7/19/2022  7:16:10 AM
Will     Off   7/19/2022  7:18:26 AM
Mason    Off   7/19/2022  8:06:51 AM
Will     On    7/19/2022  9:16:25 AM
Will     Off   7/19/2022  11:44:21 AM
```

I am looking to get a square wave using Excel for each user and then a total number of users available square wave.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done?

Comment: Do you need a chart?

Comment: I have tried to set up a countif for agent name vs time of day, but keep running into the problem of the LogDate format not matching up with time of day column.  I suspect it is because I am searching based on a time without seconds listed.